# Modify datasource IP addresses in WebSphere Application Server

Tags: ibm-was

I have nearly a hundred data sources in a WebSphere Application Server (WAS) and due to office relocation, the IP of the database servers have changed and I need to update the datasource IP addresses in my WAS too.

Considering it error-prone to update hundred IPs through admin console.

Is there any way that I can make the change by updating config files or running a script? My version of WAS is 7.0.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the WAS Admin Console's built-in "command assistance" to capture simple code snippets for listing datasources and changing them by just completing those operations in the UI once.

Take those snippets and create a new jython script to list and update all of them.

More info on command assistance:

> http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0812_rhodes/0812_rhodes.html

wsadmin scripting library:

> https://github.com/wsadminlib/wsadminlib

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using wsadmin scripting.  Covener has the right idea with using the admin console's command assistance to do the update once manually (to get the code) and then dump that into a script that you can automate.

The basic idea is that a datasource has a set of properties nested under it, one of which is the ip address.  So you want to write a script that will query for the datasource, find its nested property set, and iterate over the property set looking for the 'ipAddress' property to update.

Here is a function that will update the value of the "ipAddress" property.

```
import sys

def updateDataSourceIP(dsName, newIP):
  ds = AdminConfig.getid('/Server:myServer/JDBCProvider:myProvider/DataSource:' + dsName + '/')
  propertySet = AdminConfig.showAttribute(ds, 'propertySet')
  propertyList = AdminConfig.list('J2EEResourceProperty', propertySet).splitlines()
  for prop in propertyList:
    print AdminConfig.showAttribute(prop, 'name')
    if (AdminConfig.showAttribute(prop, 'name') == 'ipAddress'):
      AdminConfig.modify(prop, '[[value '" + newIP + "']]')
  AdminConfig.save();

# Call the function using command line args
updateDataSourceIP(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1])
```

To run this script you would invoke the following from the command line:

```
$WAS_HOME/bin/wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f /path/to/script.py myDataSource 127.0.0.1
```

**Disclaimer: untested script.  I don't know the name of the "ipAddress" property off the top of my head, but if you run this once it will print out all the properties on your ds, so you can get it there

Some useful links:

- [Basics about jython scripting](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cxml_jython.html)
- [Modifying config objects using wsadmin](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_calladminconfig.html)

Answer (score 0):

As an improvement to aguibert's script, to avoid having to provide all 100 datasource names and to update it to correct the containment path of the configuration id, consider this script which will update all datasources, regardless of the scope at which they're defined.  As always, backup your configuration before beginning and once you're satisified the script is working as expected, replace the AdminConfig.reset() with save().  Note, these scripts will likely not work properly if you're using connection URLs in your configuration.

```
import sys

def updateDataSourceIP(newIP):
  datasources = AdminConfig.getid('/DataSource:/').splitlines()
  for datasource in datasources:
    propertySet = AdminConfig.showAttribute(datasource, 'propertySet')
    propertyList = AdminConfig.list('J2EEResourceProperty', propertySet).splitlines()
    for prop in propertyList:
      if (AdminConfig.showAttribute(prop, 'name') == 'serverName'):
        oldip = AdminConfig.showAttribute(prop, 'value')
        print "Updating serverName attribute of datasource '" + datasource + "' from " + oldip + " to " + sys.argv[0]
        AdminConfig.modify(prop, '[[value ' + newIP + ']]')
        AdminConfig.reset();


# Call the function using command line arg
updateDataSourceIP(sys.argv[0])
```

The script should be invoked similarly to the above, but without the datasource parameter, the only parameter is the new hostname or ip address:

```
$WAS_HOME/bin/wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f /path/to/script.py 127.0.0.1
```